# Can't connect to University VPN on Ubuntu but same credentials works on Windows

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

My University has created VPN credentials for me during Covid-19 so I could connect to it in the pandemic.
Credentials look like this:

```
Username: my_vpn_username   
Password: my_vpn_password
VPN server: xxxx.xxxxx.edu.xx
```

Credentials worked fine on Windows till but I recently shifted to `Ubunutu 20.04` and noticed that It doesn't work on Ubuntu.
My VPN settings on Ubuntu look like this.

[image: Ubuntu VPN Setting]

**I get this error.**

[image: VPN connection error]

I don't know If I'm doing some mistake here or my University needs to change some configuration on their system. What's the possible issue on my side?

Comment: You may need Cisco-compatible VPN adapter. `sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc`

Comment: I have installed it. It requires a few fields. IPSec gateway, IPSec ID, IPSec secret, Xauth username, Xauth password, and Domain. I have username, password, and VPN Server address. What should I put in other fields? I search for IPSec ID and found out that it is some sort of group, but I don't have/know any group.

Comment: BTW, I did it somehow. check my answer If you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a few options in VPN advanced settings and it worked.

```
VPN Settings => Identity => Advanced
```

[image: VPN Setting]

**network-manager-vpnc** requires some sort of Group ID and Key called **IPSec ID** and **IPSec secret** but I have only IP, username and password.

Comment: Hello, it still doesn't work for on Ubuntu 20.04. What is your kernel version ? Windows vpn requires gre, but it seems there are no more network gre kernel module

Comment: I used it in a company PC. I don't use that anymore.